# Splitting the values of an array based on a property and then form a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an objects that contains arrays with following structure:

```
var obj  = {
  "feature1" : ["val1","val2"],
  "feature2" : ["val3"]
}
```

Now I want to split the values that are present inside of this each array and form a new array of objects that should like :

```
var result = [
  {
    "field": "feature1",
    "value": "val1",
    "type": "add"
  },
  {
    "field": "feature1",
    "value": "val2",
    "type": "add"
  },
  {
    "field": "feature2",
    "value": "val3",
    "type": "add"
  }
]
```

Here splitting must happen based on the "field" and it show something that is similar to above.here "type" is an extra field that is hardcoded

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try something first

Comment: Loop through the keys of the object and inside that, loop through each value array. Please add the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get key/value pairs, loop over them, then loop over each value in each array, and push each value into an object, back into the accumulator

```js
var obj = {
  "feature1": ["val1", "val2"],
  "feature2": ["val3"]
}

const output = Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((a, [k, v]) => a
    .concat(v
      .map(e => ({
        field: k,
        value: e,
        type: 'add'
      })
    )
  ), [])


console.log(output)
```

Or, as a one-line less readable version:

```js
var obj = {
  "feature1": ["val1", "val2"],
  "feature2": ["val3"]
}

const output = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => a.concat(v.map(e => ({field: k, value: e, type: 'add'}))), [])

console.log(output)
```

For a more performance-oriented solution, you should use plain old for loops:

```js
var obj = {
  "feature1": ["val1", "val2"],
  "feature2": ["val3"]
}

const out = []

for (var o in obj) {
  const arr = obj[o]
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out.push({
      field: o,
      value: arr[i],
      type: 'add'
    })
  }
}

console.log(out)
```

> Here is a [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-entries-reduce) to show the performance difference
>   [image: JSPerf]

---

Edit:

```js
var obj = {
  "feature1": ["1", "1", "2", "3", "1"],
  "feature2": ["val3"]
}

const output = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => a.concat([...new Set(v)].map(e => ({field: k, value: e, type: 'add'}))), [])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you . It worked. How can I avoid duplicate values , if there is one under that field? Say there is something "feature1" : ["1","2","1"], Do not want multiple values of 1

Comment: @vrosario You could use a set to remove them, I'll add an edit now.